# How to remove read-only when file gets saved?

Tags: excel, vba

How to remove `read-only` flag when file gets saved?

Because the file I work in to run this code is `read-only` it seems to save the document as `read-only`, but how to save the file so other people can still edit it?

```
comp = Environ("username")
fname = "C:\Users\" & comp & "\Testing\" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd-hh.mm") & " 
Testing " & ".xlsx"
MsgBox "Correct saved" & vbNewLine & "Yes"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Comment: You must decide, you can't have it both ways. Either is the file write-protected (read-only) or it is not.

Comment: So when you open a file thats read-only, you can't save it using this code that makes it editable???

Comment: `SaveAs` method has a `ReadOnly` parameter you can set to False

Comment: No, as previously stated, you cannot have it both ways! You need to save it with another name.

Comment: It gets saved with another name then the original file that gets opened first.

Comment: exactly @StureS , 'SaveAs' is typically used when saving the file to another name/location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys thanks for all the answers I fixed it.

```
comp = Environ("username")
fname = "C:\Users\" & comp & "\Testing\" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd-hh.mm") & " Testing " & ".xlsx"
MsgBox "Correct saved"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault, ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False, WriteresPassword:="", Password:=""
```

File gets saved now without password or read-only mode, also there won't pop-up a message saying the autor wants you to use read-only.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the access permissions for a workbook by using the `.ChangeFileAccess` method. I would also look if you are opening the workbook in read-only mode, instead of in read/write. If you opened in read/write the access should not change when you `.save` the file.

That said since you are using `.SaveAs` you can try changing the file access to `xlReadWrite` before saving it. Try:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadWrite

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try it out.

Comment: I might know what is causing a problem. To protect this file I used the file > save as > tools > general options method and then I pasted 2 passwords for opening the file and modifying the file. Is it possible to remove this protection after saving this file?

Comment: You should be able to unprotect the workbook by using  ```ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect "password"``` however I don't think it will save it unprotected if you do it after ```.SaveAs```. Try both before the ```.SaveAs``` and after but prior to the end of the the subtask

Answer (score 0):

In the line "ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook" try add ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, and FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault so:

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault, ReadOnlyRecommended:=False

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try it out.